# Auto generate a range to sum

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet where I collect orders from customers. each item is entered in a row & qty is in next column then other item is in next row. hence the no of row is depending on number of items ordered by customer and after each customer's order there is blank row. What I want is to auto sum total qty ordered just after the blank row (OR in a cell in blank row) . for this I have done mentioned below  -
Suppose order qty is in column "L" & I want the sum in column "M".

for this I have first row number in Column "N" like 5 using formula

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($C7)),ROW(),$N6
```

Last row number in Column "O" like 10 using formula
    =ROW()-1

Now I use this formula to sum qty from row 5:10 in column "L"

```
=SUM("L"&IF(NOT(ISBLANK($C7)),ROW(),$N6))
```

it is returning #Value1! error, is there any mistake to put formula OR any other way to do this please guide me.

Comment: You will have to use the INDIRECT function to be able to use a string as a range. Since your question is pretty unclear, It would be best to provide an image with sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Thank a lot it works !